# How do I sum together file sizes in bash, grouping together the results by date?

Tags: bash, file

On a Linux server that I work with, a process writes randomly-named files at random intervals. Here's a small sample, showing the file size, modification date & time, and file name:

```
27659   2009-03-09  17:24  APP14452.log
0       2009-03-09  17:24  vim14436.log
20      2009-03-09  17:24  jgU14406.log
15078   2009-03-10  08:06  ySh14450.log
20      2009-03-10  08:06  VhJ14404.log
9044    2009-03-10  15:14  EqQ14296.log
8877    2009-03-10  19:38  Ugp14294.log
8898    2009-03-11  18:21  yzJ14292.log
55629   2009-03-11  18:30  ZjX14448.log
20      2009-03-11  18:31  GwI14402.log
25955   2009-03-12  19:19  lRx14290.log
14989   2009-03-12  19:25  oFw14446.log
20      2009-03-12  19:28  clg14400.log
```

(Note that sometimes the file size can be zero.)

What I would like is a bash script to sum the size of the files, broken down by date, producing output something like this (assuming my arithmetic is correct):

```
27679 2009-03-09
33019 2009-03-10
64527 2009-03-11
40964 2009-03-12
```

The results would show activity trends over time, and highlight the exceptionally busy days.

In SQL, the operation would be a cinch:

```
SELECT SUM(filesize), filedate
FROM files
GROUP BY filedate;
```

Now, this is all probably pretty easy in Perl or Python, but I'd really prefer a bash shell or awk solution. It seems especially tricky to me to group the files by date in bash (especially if you can't assume a particular date format). Summing the sizes could be done in a loop I suppose, but is there an easier, more elegant, approach?

Comment: actually you can assume date format with ls -lt --time-style=+%F

Comment: Yes, thanks for that. Together with the solution from @ashawley , it's all come together.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I often use this idiom of Awk:

```
awk '{sum[$2]+= $1;}END{for (date in sum){print sum[date], date;}}'
```

Comment: That's beautiful. I didn't realize awk supported dictionaries so simply.

Comment: Where can I specify the year?

Answer (score 11):

Only files, recursively, sorted by date and summed

```
find ./ -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td %s\n'|awk '{sum[$1]+= $2;}END{for (date in sum){print date, sum[date];}}'|sort
```

Only files, from current directory only, sorted by date and summed

```
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td %s\n'|awk '{sum[$1]+= $2;}END{for (date in sum){print date, sum[date];}}'|sort
```

Answer (score 8):

(find ...  | xargs stat "--printf=%s+"; echo 0) | bc

Comment: This is a very good answer. Also, you should use `find -print0 | xargs -0`, just in case (unless you know your files are all named nicely).

Answer (score 3):

Following the suggestions from ashawley and vartec, the following "one-liner" does the trick superbly:

```
ls -l --time-style=long-iso *log |
    awk '{sum[$6]+= $5;}END{for (s in sum){print sum[s], s;}}' |
    sort -k2 |
    column -t
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider that on Linux you probably have GNU awk,
so you don't need other commands:

```
ls -l --time-style=long-iso * | 
  WHINY_USERS=-9 awk 'END {
    for (s in sum)
      printf "%-15s\t%s\n", sum[s], s
      }
  { sum[$6]+= $5 }
  '
```

Answer (score 0):

There a tool I've created which allows performing SQL-like queries against text data, including grouping, joins, conditions and other stuff. You can take a look [here](https://github.com/harelba/q) for details.